# Транслитор на С++

Tags: c++

При компиляции с `cout<<Start[i];` выдает ошибку

> debuger expantion notification

А если с `cout<<Start;` или `cout<<End;`, то такая ошибка

> [BCC32 Error] File1.cpp(215): E2094 'operator<<' not implemented in type 'ostream' for arguments of type 'AnsiString'
>  Full parser context
>  File1.cpp(210): parsing: int main()

Код:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream.h>
   #include <conio.h>
 Translit()
{
AnsiString Start, End;
   int dl, i;
   {
    for (i=1; i<=dl; i++)
   {
      switch (Start[i]) {
         case 'а':
            End = End + "a";
            break;
         case 'А':
            End = End + "A";
            break;
         case 'б':
            End = End + "b";
            break;
         case 'Б':
            End = End + "B";
            break;
         case 'в':
            End = End + "v";
            break;
         case 'В':
            End = End + "V";
            break;
         case 'г':
            End = End + "g";
            break;
         case 'Г':
            End = End + "G";
            break;
         case 'д':
            End = End + "d";
            break;
         case 'Д':
            End = End + "D";
            break;
         case 'е':
         case 'ё':
            End = End + "e";
            break;
         case 'Е':
         case 'Ё':
            End = End + "E";
            break;
         case 'ж':
            End = End + "j";
            break;
         case 'Ж':
            End = End + "J";
            break;
         case 'з':
            End = End + "z";
            break;
         case 'З':
            End = End + "Z";
            break;
         case 'и':
         case 'ы':
            End = End + "i";
            break;
         case 'И':
         case 'Ы':
            End = End + "I";
            break;
         case 'й':
            End = End + "y";
            break;
         case 'Й':
            End = End + "Y";
            break;
         case 'к':
            End = End + "k";
            break;
         case 'К':
            End = End + "K";
            break;
         case 'л':
            End = End + "l";
            break;
         case 'Л':
            End = End + "L";
            break;
         case 'м':
            End = End + "m";
            break;
         case 'М':
            End = End + "M";
            break;
         case 'н':
            End = End + "n";
            break;
         case 'Н':
            End = End + "N";
            break;
         case 'о':
            End = End + "o";
            break;
         case 'О':
            End = End + "O";
            break;
         case 'п':
            End = End + "p";
            break;
         case 'П':
            End = End + "P";
            break;
         case 'р':
            End = End + "r";
            break;
         case 'Р':
            End = End + "R";
            break;
         case 'с':
            End = End + "s";
            break;
         case 'С':
            End = End + "S";
            break;
         case 'т':
            End = End + "t";
            break;
         case 'Т':
            End = End + "T";
            break;
         case 'у':
            End = End + "u";
            break;
         case 'У':
            End = End + "U";
            break;
         case 'ф':
            End = End + "f";
            break;
         case 'Ф':
            End = End + "F";
            break;
         case 'х':
            End = End + "kh";
            break;
         case 'Х':
            End = End + "Kh";
            break;
         case 'ц':
            End = End + "cs";
            break;
         case 'Ц':
            End = End + "Cs";
            break;
         case 'ч':
            End = End + "ch";
            break;
         case 'Ч':
            End = End + "Ch";
            break;
         case 'ш':
            End = End + "sh";
            break;
         case 'Ш':
            End = End + "Sh";
            break;
         case 'щ':
            End = End + "sh";
            break;
         case 'Щ':
            End = End + "Sh";
            break;
         case 'ъ':
         case 'Ъ':
            End = End + "'";
            break;
         case 'ь':
         case 'Ь':
            End = End;
            break;
         case 'э':
            End = End + "ie";
            break;
         case 'Э':
            End = End + "Ie";
            break;
         case 'ю':
            End = End + "ju";
            break;
         case 'Ю':
            End = End + "Ju";
            break;
         case 'я':
            End = End + "ja";
            break;
         case 'Я':
            End = End + "Ja";
            break;
         default:
            End = End + Start[i];
            break;
      }
   }
   }
   }
   int main()
   {
   AnsiString Start, End;
   int dl, i;
   Translit();
    End = AnsiString("");
      cout<<Start;

      getch();
   }
```

Comment: а где `using namespace std;` ?

Comment: и чем он мне поможет? если оно не хочет компилировать cout<<Start;

Comment: оно поможет, так как в новых компиляторах (лет так десять уже) cout находится в пространстве имен std, которое не подключается автоматически.
Но если у Вас старый древнющий компилятор, то другое дело:)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант решения - `cout << Start.c_str();`

У борландовских `AnsiString` не определены соответствующие методы типа `ostream& operator<<`, поэтому напрямую выводить их в поток нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

По теме тебе уже ответили, но могу показать, как избавиться от этого огромного switch'а:

```
//Пропуски ... заполнишь сам
char* transmap1['Я'-'А'+1]={"A", "B", "V", "G", ..., "Ya"};
char* transmap2['я'-'а'+1]={"a", "b", "v", ..., "ya"};
for (i=1; i<=dl; i++)
{
    if(Start[i]>='А' && Start[i]<='Я') End+=transmap1[Start[i]];
    else if(Start[i]>='а' && Start[i]<='я') End+=transmap2[Start[i]];
    else End+=Start[i];
}
```

Используй лучше стандартные строки string. cout их понимает.